# Laravel worker set dynamic retry_after

Tags: php, laravel

Have a Laravel 5.7 app with a single Job class.  The job itself will fetch data and process it.
The amount of data (and therefore the length of time the job takes) can vary massively so wanted to have a dynamic timeout based on the runtime of the past n jobs (the details are stored so can  be queried).

This would work in that I can set `public $timeout = n` in the class but the `retry_after` value can only be set on CLI or in the `config/queue.php` as the `public $retryAfter` in the class has a different function (according to https://divinglaravel.com/explaining-laravel-queue-configuration-keys).

Is there any way that at runtime I can set the `retry_after` value dynamically?

For info, absolutely cannot hard set a value due to the way the app works (and refactoring other code in the app is a no-go), and the time it takes to run will always be an unknown so just creating separate long running queues or things like that won't work either.